# Subdomain with aws Route 53 is not accessbile (Wix Reding Page)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have one main domain (example.com) and one subdomain (api.example.com).

This main domain was purchased from a domain site called Gabia.

Afterwards, I created a hosted zone called example.com in AWS Route 53 and registered Route 53's name server in Gabia's name server as shown in the first picture below.

Also, I registered the ALB that I made for the rest api server under the alias A type of example.com and it worked fine.

However, the problem started when I registered the Wix homepage on my example.com through a pointing method.

The A and CName types required for the pointing method were added to the AWS Route 53 domain area of ​​example.com as shown in the second picture below, and the ALB for rest api that was originally connected to example.com was changed to api.example.com.

Then Wix's homepage worked, but api.example.com started returning "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN".

What are the solutions I can take in this situation?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you access the ALB? what does it return?

Comment: Oh, now it works! Maybe, it was a problem of TTL. @FranxiHidro